# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "login" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to solve this problem? I am new into NodeJS.
This is my Model User:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

This is my route file, i mean this /login route where i call get method on authuser function

```
router.post('/login', authUser);
```

And this is my authUser function:

```
const authUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  res.send({ email, password });
};
```

Simple function without any logic but i just want to see respond, i use postman to auth user and i get that error in console...

Comment: I think the problem should be in another part of your code. In your authUser function you are not even using the User model. Maybe in a middleware?

Comment: @Pipe i make function to register user, get all users, get user by id, just this one give error, i will try to find solution